# How do I determine the Execution Context for a JavaScript callback function?

Tags: javascript

When a function is called as an object property, `this` is set to the parent object. There are similar rules that apply to calling a function as a Constructor, or an event handler, but after browsing more articles on JS Scope than I can count, and digging into the ECMA5.1 specification, I've been unable to sort out exactly how Execution Context is set when a function is passed as a callback.

This code makes it clear that a method passed as a callback to another method, even within the same object, reverts to the global Execution Context (both in a browser and in Node.js).

```
var name = 'global';
var self = function() {
    return this.name;
}
var cback = function(ff) {
    return ff();
}
var parent = {
    name: 'parent',
    cback: function(ff) {
        return ff();
    },
    self: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
console.log(parent.cback(parent.self));  // Returns "global"
```

Can anyone help me understand ***why*** the callback is executed in a global context instead of within the `parent` object's context? My best guess is that any function passed as an argument has its previous execution context replaced when it's assigned to a local variable (`ff` in the example above), which means invoking it passes an undefined thisArg and devolves to global context (barring strict mode, or being attached as a method to a new object before execution), but I'm hesitant to rely on that without it being a bit more than a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for `this` in callbacks are the same as the rules for non-method functions. The thing that really matters is if the function call looks like `f()` (non-method),  `x.f()` (method call) or `new f()` (constructor)

> Can anyone help me understand why the callback is executed in a global context instead of within the parent object's context?

Sadly, this is one of those big Javascript warts that we have to live with. That said, if you are running in strict mode the `this` is `null` instead of the global object, which is more sane. Additionally, in ES6 there will be ["fat arrow" `=>` lambdas](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/), which inherit the `this` from their lexical context (this means it gets its `this` from the outer function, just like regular variables)

Comment: But why does a method passed as a callback get treated as a non-method function?

To clarify, I've empirically determined what the code sample does. I'm trying to get enough context about why to understand how to apply the same rules elsewhere.

Comment: Because when you call the callback you call it with `ff()`, the same way you would call a regular function. Also keep in mind that `function f(){}` is the same thing as `var f = function(){}`, up to hoisting.

Comment: Because javascript method does not carry information about the object instance whose method it is. The same function can be assigned as a method of more than one different objects/prototypes. This is different from methods in such languages as C# or Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

> how Execution Context is set when a function is passed as a callback

I think the key to understanding is that those processes are completely independent.

> any function passed as an argument has its previous execution context replaced when it's assigned to a local variable

Not really. A function by itself does not have any execution context at all.

The execution context only gets created **when calling** the function. And only how the function is called determines the properties of the execution context, such as its `this` value.

For example,

> When a function is called as an object property, `this` is set to the parent object.

such as `parent.cback(…)`. The called function being referenced by a property, the base reference (`parent`) will become the `this` context of the call.

Alternatively, when a function is called as a plain function, `this` is set to `undefined` (or the global object in sloppy mode) - such as `ff()`.

For the other alternatives, have a look at the [MDN refernce on the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).